# Error in installing Bundle for Vim

Tags: vim, plugins

I was tiring to install bundle for vim.
I input :BundleInstall, and it seems fail to install

```
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'                         |~ 
Bundle 'file:///Users/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
```

The log shows that

```
[131205 15:35:35] Bundle git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git               |~                                                                         
[131205 15:35:35] $ git clone --recursive 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.|~                                                                         
git' '/home/p/.vim/bundle/command-t'                                       |~                                                                         
[131205 15:35:35] > fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer^@Cloning in|~                                                                         
to '/home/p/.vim/bundle/command-t'...^@                                    |~                                                                         
[131205 15:35:36]                                                          |~                                                                         
[131205 15:35:36] Bundle file:///Users/gmarik/path/to/plugin               |~                                                                         
[131205 15:35:36] $ git clone --recursive 'file:///Users/gmarik/path/to/plu|~                                                                         
gin' '/home/p/.vim/bundle/plugin'                                          |~                                                                         
[131205 15:35:36] > Cloning into '/home/p/.vim/bundle/plugin'...^@fatal: '/|~                                                                         
Users/gmarik/path/to/plugin' does not appear to be a git repository^@fatal:|~                                                                         
 Could not read from remote repository.^@^@Please make sure you have the co|~                                                                         
rrect access rights^@and the repository exists.^@
```

How to fix it？

Comment: So, you've got a network error and apparently configured a non-Git bundle, which the package manager doesn't like. What's your question?!

Comment: How to fix it？ I tried several times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those two errors occurs because you've misunderstood the Vundle installation.
What you see on the GitHub repo (https://github.com/gmarik/vundle#about) is a **sample** config.

You don't need the two lines that gives you the errors as you don't have access to them (one's probably a private GIT while the other is a local file), so just remove those lines in your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you could try to point to the github mirror:
https://github.com/wincent/Command-T.git
For the second one, unless you are developing your own vim plugins, just comment it out or delete it.